# PreBuild Definition || Execution of script

Tags: tfs, build, definition

How to run scripts in build definition (preBuild) in TFS2013? I don't see any option for PreBuild Definition for script run.

Comment: What build process template are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run a PowerShell script or a batch (.bat) file before the system compiles or tests your code. You can use **Default Template( TfvcTemplate.12.xaml )** which include the Pre-Build Script options. More info from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353(v=vs.120).aspx).

[image]

If you can't change the build template, you can custom your build template to meet the needs. Detail guides from official https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551(v=vs.120).aspx You can also learn about the process in the [ALM Rangers Build Guidance](http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/)